# How to open the TortoiseGit log window from command line?

Tags: tortoisegit

How can you show the standard TortoiseGit log window for a repository or specified file in repository from the command line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call TortoiseGit's 'show log' by commandline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34016652/call-tortoisegits-show-log-by-commandline)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you're currently in a working copy directory, you can run this command:

```
TortoiseGitProc /command:log /path:.
```

Or to just show the log of a specific file, use:

```
TortoiseGitProc /command:log /path:MyFile.txt
```

I haven't yet worked out how to specify a certain branch/remote, however.

Comment: @StevePitchers Yes I think you're correct, thank you.  My answer from several years ago appears outdated, so I've updated it. :-)

Comment: I created a bash alias for it in `~/.bashrc` using `alias tgit="TortoiseGitProc.exe /command:log"` so I can just launch it using `tgit`.

Answer (score 9):

Assume `C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin` is in `%PATH%`

Since 1.8.0

```
TortoiseGitProc.exe /command:log
```

will show log of repository in current directory.

```
TortoiseGitProc.exe /command:log /path:C:\Repo1\MyFile1.txt
TortoiseGitProc.exe /command:log /path:MyFile1.txt
```

will show the change log of `MyFile1.txt`

Note that `MyFile1.txt` part is case sensitive, `C:\Repo1\` part is not case sensitive.

Note: 1.7.15 and older use `TortoiseProc.exe`