# Call TortoiseGit's 'show log' by commandline

Tags: git, cmd, tortoisegit

When entering a git-directory through the commandline in Windows I want a commandline which shows me the Tortoisegit's *show log* GUI.

So I want to avoid the open explorer->go to folder-click right->etc. thing, but I still want the nice looking *show log* graph of Tortoisegit.

How do I perform this in the cmd?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you are in command line interface (assume the PATH is good), just use:

**TortoiseGitProc /command:log**

otherwise,

**TortoiseGitProc /command:log /path:"the\path\you\want\to\open\log"**

---

cf. [TortoiseGit Manual - Appendix D. Automating TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-automation.html)

---

For getting the exact command argument, go to TortoiseGit -> Settings -> Advanced tree node -> set Option "Debug" value to true.

Then open the log via normal way, you will get extra message dialog. Something like:

[image]

Then use *Ctrl + C* to copy the whole message, and paste it to somewhere, ex: notepad, and reuse the command line.

(BTW, you can easily ignore the /hwnd argument.)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the command line waiting for the TortoiseGit window to close:

`start "" "TortoiseGitProc" /command:log`

I went a step further and created a file named `tg.bat` in `C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin` with the above line in.

Now all I need to type is this:

`tg`