# TortoiseGit Commit Window Opens via Command Line, But Not via Context Menu (Same with Merge Window)

Tags: tortoisegit, windows-11

I have been struggling with my new work computer, and have Reset Windows on it (and reinstalled TortoiseGit along the way) several times this month. Finally, the IT department formatted it and did a clean installation of Windows 11, and I got the machine back this morning. Installed TortoiseGit yet again as part of getting the machine ready for use, and everything went as smoothly as before - until the first time I tried to commit.

When I select 'Commit -> "main"' from the Windows 11 TortoiseGit context menu, or from the "old" context menu, the mouse cursor changes to show activity, then returns to normal, and the Commit window never appears!

Immediately I tried the other options in the context menu, and everything seems to work (Pull, Push, Diff, View Log, Settings, and Clone were all tested, and maybe others too).

I also tried on different git repositories to ensure it's not a problem with one specific repo, but the behaviour is the same on any repo.

I tried restarting the computer. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling TortoiseGit (I am on v2.14.0.1). I tried uninstalling, then restarting, then reinstalling, then restarting. I tried uninstalling, then restarting, and then installing an older version (v2.13.0.1 - later I updated to v2.14.0.1 again). I have also switched to a different branch and trying to Commit there, but the window still doesn't appear.

Finally, I tried changing the menus in the TortoiseGit settings, hoping that moving the Commit option to a sub-menu might trigger some kind of refresh and make the Commit option work again, however this also made no difference (although I admit this was grasping at straws).

While working on this question, I did come across an unrelated answer where I learned the TortoiseGit windows may be opened from the command line (see: [How to open the TortoiseGit log window from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562210/how-to-open-the-tortoisegit-log-window-from-command-line)). I tried opening the Commit window this way (using the command below after changing directory to one of my repos), and it worked!

```
TortoiseGitProc /command:commit
```

So the problem seems to be only with the context menu option to Commit - for some reason the window fails to open from here. Does anyone have any idea what might have caused this and, more importantly, how to fix it?

Update: Tried to Merge for the first time today and the Merge window also doesn't open - I have to use the same `TortoiseGitProc` workaround to open that window.